# Opposite of Therewithal

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, antonyms, archaicisms

Below is the definition of therewithal according to google and several other sources.

**Therewithal**: together with that; besides.
*"he was to make a voyage and his fortune therewithal"*

I was searching for a proper antonym for the word, such as "therewithout" (sadly it's not a real word), yet couldn't find anything. The sentence I'm trying to compose is as follows:

"In order to observe if these isopods would discriminate between environments with soil and other terrestrial environments **(therewithout)...**"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Honestly, I would advise against words of this kind; if you have the wherewithal to check the OED, you'll find that *withal* and its compounds other than *wherewithal* are largely archaic or obsolete; the synonym *therewith* is archaic or formal. *Without* is perfectly suitable here, or you can employ an adjective phrase like *devoid of* or *free of*.

Comment: Nicholas, you're right, there is no direct antonym for *therewhithal*.

Still, could you find a better example than *In order to observe if these isopods would discriminate between environments with soil and other terrestrial environments (therewithout)...* or is it fine that everyone should think three times about the difference between *environments* and *environments*?

Reduce that to *… discriminate between environments and other environments (therewithout)…* and does it not become clear that example’s simply not comparable to the *therewithal* definition?

Comment: The term is archaic and the would discriminate is wrong in a formal text.

Comment: Google is a search engine, not a dictionary. If you have found something using the google search engine please give the link and provide the correct attribution. Anyone can put up a website with the most appalling nonsense and Google will index it.